# how to get javascript variable in java? (like javascript parser?)

Tags: java

like code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String content="<HTML>"
     +"<HEAD><TITLE>title</TITLE></HEAD>"
     +"<BODY>"
     +"<script>var jsvar=123;</script>"
     +"</div>"
     +"</BODY>"
     +"</HTML>"
    ;
}
```

in this case,how to get `jsvar` variable value?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute JavaScript code in Java, You can use scripting API of Java 6 and Java 6 is included with Mozilla Rhino engine.

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jsEngine.eval("jsvar = 123");
System.out.println(jsEngine.get("jsvar")); //prints 123.0
```

**Reference:** http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this is backward. If you are serving the page then you already have the value on the server. I would inject the value from Java into JavaScript not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you're asking something that requires a browser. As a consequence, you may have to take a look at [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which could solve your issue.

However, were you to directly run *pure* javascript code from Java, you would have better using a Javascript interpreter like [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) (I think).